# Determine length from sketch

Tags: triangles

I have a simple problem that I need to solve.  Given a height (in blue), and an angle (eg: 60-degrees), I need to determine the length of the line in red, based on where the green line ends.  The green line comes from the top of the blue line and is always 90-degrees.

The height of the blue line is variable.
The angle of the blue line is variable.

Also, I do not know the length of the green dashed-line. Is there a way to figure out the length of the red line without knowing the length of the green?

-Adam

Any help would be much appreciated!

-Adam

[image]

Comment: $\cos 60=\frac{10}{\color{red}{red}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're dealing with right triangle, you can just use cosine function:

$$\cos(\theta)=\frac{blue}{red}$$

Or, substituting $60^o$ for $\theta$ and 10 for *blue*:

$$\cos(60^o)=\frac{10}{red}$$

Thus, solving for the length of the red side:

$$red=\frac{blue}{\cos(\theta)}$$

Or

$$red=\frac{10}{\cos(60^o)} = 20$$

Answer (score 3):

Use Law of sines, $$\frac{a}{\sin{A}}=\frac{b}{\sin{B}}=\frac{c}{\sin{C}}$$

Let,

$\angle{A}=60^o$

$\angle{B}=90^o$

$\angle{C}=30^o$

$a=?$

$b=?$

$c=10cm$

From Law of sines we have,

$$\frac{a}{\sin{A}}=\frac{c}{\sin{C}}$$

Put the values and find $a$.

Now, from Law of sines we have,

$$\frac{a}{\sin{A}}=\frac{b}{\sin{B}}$$

Put the known values and find $b$.

Congratulations, you are done!

Comment: The problem is that I do not know the length of the green dashed-line.
Also, I will need to turn this in to software.  Is there a way to help express this in a format I can use (C++/Objective-C, etc)?  Much thanks

Comment: Sorry Adam, I don't know how to covert this into programming. I am myself a student and still learning. May be any other person could help. And also, you should have added the following request in your question. Anyways, all the best!

Comment: These are great help, but the problem is that I do not know the length of the green dashed-line. Is there a way to figure out the length of the red line without knowing the length of the green?

-Adam

Comment: Yes, of course! There is a way which is clear in my answer. If you want to know the length of red line without determining the length of green dashed-line then use only, $$\frac{b}{\sin{B}}=\frac{c}{\sin{C}}$$. where, $b$ is the length of red line (to be determined) and $c$ is the length of blue line ($10cm$). $\angle{B}=90^o$ and $\angle{C}=30^o$. Did you see, you didn't find any need to find the length of green dashed line for finding the length of red line. So, therefore, my answer is still an answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

Reflect at the green line to obtain a triangle, which must be equilateral.